# Can I pass a function callback to headless js in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I find I can pass some String or other primitive types by using `bundle.putString("foo", "bar");`
or `putBoolean` etc. like below:

```
Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTaskService.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("foo", "bar");
service.putExtras(bundle);

getApplicationContext().startService(service);
```

But how can I pass a function call back to the headless js service?

ref. [react native headless js page](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android)